# Div do resize in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript

My page has one div on which I have set property `resize` to `both`. It resizes in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

```
document.getElementById('IdDivMain').style.height = "394px"
document.getElementById('IdDivMain').style.resize = "both";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why doesn't it work in Internet Explorer**
The `resize` property is not supported in internet explorer at all - have not found out about Edge thought

**Why doesn't it work in firefox**
According to [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

> resize does not apply to blocks for which the overflow property is set to visible.

The default `overflow` (for divs at least) is `visible` - so, setting the overflow to something other than `visible` should allow `resize` to do it's thing

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle, or put some running code in your question - I think you (and me too) have misunderstood what the resize property does